# I filter items using a check_box_tag helper, how do I accomplish the same filtering using the link_to helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, link-to

I have a page where I need to send parameters so that the url looks like this:

```
/my_controller?stores%5BStoreName%5D=1
```

However, when I try to form my `link_to` I get this url:

```
/my_controller?stores%5B%5D=5BStoreName&stores%5B%5D=1
```

This is the link_to code from my view:

```
<%= link_to store, my_controller_path(:stores => [store, 1]) %>
```

How do I change my code so that I get the url structured with the params that match the link that I need?

My params should look like `{"stores"=>{"StoreName"=>"1"}` , but right now they look like `{"stores"=>["StoreName", "1"]`.

**Controller:**

Here is the index method within my controller that is reading this hash - for clarity.

```
def index    
  @all_stores = Product.all_stores
  @selected_stores = params[:stores] || session[:stores] || {}

  if @selected_stores == {}
    @selected_stores = Hash[@all_stores.map {|store| [store, store]}]
  end
  if params[:stores] != session[:stores]
    session[:stores] = params[:stores]
    redirect_to :stores => @selected_stores and return
  end
  @products = Product.order("created_at desc").limit(150).find_all_by_store(@selected_stores.keys).group_by { |product| product.created_at.to_date}
  . . . etc
```

**Background:**

The bigger picture here is that the destination page (that the above link will link to) is a page that lists all products filtered by store.  The way the filter normally works is with a set of checkboxes (the user can mark checkboxes to show products from specific stores).  The desired link will take users directly to this page with the desired filter already applied - without having to mark checkboxes.

For additional reference, here is that checkbox helper that filters that destination page's products:

```
<%= check_box_tag "stores[#{store}]", 1, @selected_stores.include?(store), :id => "stores_#{store}" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<%= link_to store, my_controller_path(:stores => { store => 1}) %>`

Comment: That gives me the following error: `#<NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass>` when I try to render the page with the link_to helper on it.  Also, I get the same error in my console when I try 'my_controller_path(:stores => { store => 1})' .  Maybe I have a null value somewhere - let me see. . .

Comment: It shouldn't be null, as my improperly formatted link_to link uses the same 'store' variable - and it isn't null. . .  However, when I hardcode a store string in place of `{ store => 1 }` (i.e. `{ "Sephora" => 1 }` the link works just fine.  I must have something else wrong here somewhere.

Comment: The first `store` has a value, but when I get to the `store` within the hash it has a nil value.

Comment: can you update your post to include the line that sets `store`?

Comment: ok that's what's most probably triggering the error. do you have a default store name?

Comment: Actually - just did this: `<%= link_to store, my_controller_path(:stores => { store.to_s => 1}) %>` and things seem to work.  I find it odd that it would say the value of store was nil unless I called .to_s on it.  Any clue?

Comment: `nil.to_s` returns a blank string

Comment: Ah, so there must have been one situation (this link is rendered many different times) where store was actually nil.  Makes sense - Thank you very much.